# Labeling a 2D java array

Tags: java, arrays

I have created a 2D array and want to print the output. I want to label the columns and rows. I have labeled the rows. but I can not figure out how to label the columns.  Something link this:

```
   A B C D E F
```

Row 1  * * * * * *
Row 2  * * * * * *
Row 3  * * * * * *
Row 4  * * * * * *
Row 5  * * * * * *
Row 6  * * * * * *
Row 7  * * * * * *
Row 8  * * * * * *
Row 9  * * * * * *
Row 10 * * * * * *
Row 11 * * * * * *
Row 12 * * * * * *
Row 13 * * * * * *

Like I said I have the rows and the *, but how do I get the A b c labels on the columns.

```
 for(int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
 {
    System.out.print("Row " + i + " " );

     for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
     { 
        System.out.print(seats[i][j] + " ");

      }
        System.out.println(); //for spacing 
   }
```

Comment: do you mean that you want to label the columns in spreadsheet style ie 'A','B'...'AA','AB'... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you know how many columns you have and it's less than 26, you could add this on to the start of your code...

```
for (int j = 0; j < seats[0].length; j++)
    System.out.print(((char) ('A' + j)) + "\t");
System.out.println();
```

going past 26 is a little more complex, let me know if you need that.

Comment: it's a good idea to make your code more scalable by using the actual lengths of the arrays to determine ranges. ie instead of hard coding 6 columns in the loop definition, use seats[0].length, and instead of using 13 in your other loop use seats.length.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add something like

```
System.out.println("       A B C D E F");
```

before the loop shown in the question.

I'm assumming each element of the array is a single character wide, adapt accordingly if that were not the case.  Also, the leading spaces are to account for the "Row ##" header shown on each subsequent line.

Also [unrelated to the question], rather than using **hard-coded values** for the limits of the loop (here 6 and 13), use the **arrays' length attribute** instead, i.e.

```
 for(int i = 1; i < seats.length; i++)
 {
    System.out.print("Row " + i + " " );

     for(int j = 0; j < seats[i].length; j++)
     { 
        System.out.print(seats[i][j] + " ");

      }
      System.out.println(); //for spacing 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do two things - create labels and format the output. To create the labels I would do something like

```
char a = 'A';
for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    char label = a+j;
    System.out.print(label);
    System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.println();
```

but this will give a messy output.

I would personally create an HTML table to do the formatting - working it out yourself is tedious.